# Convert Long Date / Time to user friendly one PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

well I have an api returning a date in this format

2010-10-22 07:00:00 Etc/GMT

how can I change that so it's

October 22, 2010

using php

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print strftime('%B %e, %Y',strtotime('2010-10-22 07:00:00 Etc/GMT'));
```

Outputs: "October 22, 2010"

How's that? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this functions :

1. [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) for getting the unixtimestamp,
2. [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/function.strftime.php) for outputing a nice formatted time expression.

Answer (score 2):

1. Parse the date using [strptime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)
2. Convert that to a timestamp using [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)
3. Format the timestamp using [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: strptime() is system-dependent. Therefore, [date_parse_from_format()](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format), which is not, is recommended for PHP 5.3.0 and above. (Unfortunately, the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) does not observe the locale.) However, simon's [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) solution is more efficient if you know that the input string is in a recognized format (such as ISO 8601). So +1 to both.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($dt));
```

Comment: i believe Etc/GMT was causing a problem with this one, since the strtotime always returned nothing.

Comment: @Belgin Fish: huh? 1) it works for me 2) you checked **the same** answer, given **later** that mine.

Comment: @Belgin Fish: did you get that `$dt` variable stores your date string?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime($date))
```

Comment: i believe Etc/GMT was causing a problem with this one, since the strtotime always returned nothing.